# How would I modify handleSubmit for deployment in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku

I'm deploying my portfolio to Firebase. I have a contact page, and it will send information to a backend, that I plan to deploy to Heroku.

I'm not sure what I would change the localhost in handleSubmit to. How would I modify this if I were deploying?

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.validate()) {
            console.log(e.target);
            this.setState({
                disabled: true,
                emailSent: null
            });
            Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/email', this.state)
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.data.success) {
                        this.setState({
                            emailSent: true
                        });
                        this.clearForm();
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            disabled: false,
                            emailSent: false
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you heard of environment variables?

Comment: I'm a little familiar with them?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions based on your case. You haven't provided enough details for me to give you a definitive answer. But here's what you can try:

If your application is deployed within the same domain, then you can use a relative path, as in:

```js
Axios.post('/api/email', this.state)
```

If your application is not deployed within the same domain, then you have to inject this variable into the code. The best way you can go about doing that is by utilizing node's process `process.argv`. Anything related to the process will be read and processed by webpack (I'm assuming that's what you are using). Then, you would inject the API URL during the build pipeline right before deployment. Your build would look like this:

```
npm run build --api-url=http://yourdomain/url/to/apis
```

In your code, you will have to grab that URL and use it. It would look something like this:

```js
// Get the arguments from the process
let args = process.argv.slice(2); // first 2 are node specific

// Try to find the api-url you passed
let argsApiUrl = args.filter(arg => arg.startsWith('--api-url'))[0];

// Use it if it exist, otherwise, use the localhost
let apiUrl = argsApiUrl
                 ? argsApiUrl.split('=')[1]
                 : 'http://localhost:4000/api/email';
```

And then use the URL in your call

```js
Axios.post(apiUrl, this.state)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to deploy within the same domain if the backend is in Heroku and the front end is it Firebase?

Comment: Firebase and Heroku are hosting services, they need a domain anyway right? You could have multiple applications deployed separately while they all point towards one domain. We had a setup like that before where the frontend would be in the root `/` and the backend apis are pointing towards `/api/`

Comment: So how would I do this if my root domain, mydomain.com, is my static page, while my backend is api.mydomain.com?

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, subdomains are considered different domains. You will have to rely on injecting the api url during the build pipeline just I mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't just put the api url in??

Comment: You can, if you are only working with one environment. I thought that's the whole point, you have multiple environements. I usually take out all of these constants into a file named `configs.ts` and if the environement changes, I only inject new values to that file,